# Can not create Confluence page, any idea why?

Tags: jira, confluence

When creating an empty page in Confluence, wheel keeps spinning,  I see following error in browser. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

`TypeError: e.replace is not a function. (In 'e.replace(n,"⌘")', 'e.replace' is undefined)`

[image]

Comment: Confluence Cloud?

Comment: Yes, confluence cloud. Today it is working. Maybe Atlassian was down yesterday evening but only for this function?

Comment: The error looks like something went wrong when loading resources for collaborative editing (Synchrony). There was an error logged about this: https://status.atlassian.com/incidents/zn0fdfqzn71w

Comment: You mean someone might edited the same page, did not completed it, and page was locked?

Comment: No. I think it is probable that Atlassian had some problem sending this resource related to collaborative editing and it was causing the problem.